# Coalesce with comparisons

Tags: postgresql, coalesce

I'm trying to simplify some nesting `CASE WHEN` logic for my postgres SQL query. I was told [COALESCE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/functions-conditional.html) can help. But it appears `COALESCE` is good for using the next value its provided if the previous are `NULL`, not necessarily comparisons.

For example, My logic is such that I have cascading checks. The excel Logic I'm trying to replicate looks like:

```
=IF(W3="X",
    IF(
        ISERROR(
            INDEX(
                'LOOKUP A'!$L:$L,MATCH($AC3,'LOOKUP A'!$J:$J,0)
            )   
       ),
       'LOOKUP A'!$L$2,
        INDEX(
            'LOOKUP A'!$L:$L,MATCH($AC3,'CSR Product City'!$J:$J,0)
        )
    ), IFERROR(

        /*
            If Not LOOKUP B
                Then LOOKUP C
                    Then LOOKUP D
        */
        INDEX(
            'LOOKUP B'!$I:$I,MATCH($Y3,'LOOKUP B'!$P:$P,0)
        ),
        IFERROR(
            INDEX(
                'LOOKUP C'!$H:$H,MATCH($Z3,'LOOKUP C'!$O:$O,0)
            ),
            IFERROR(
                INDEX(
                    LOOKUP D!$G:$G,MATCH($S3,LOOKUP D!$A:$A,0)
                ),
                LOOKUP D!$G$2
            )
        )
    )
)
```

Which comes out as such in SQL. I'd like to use COALESCE but I'm not sure how in this case because I don't see how I can do a `IF a.val == b.val THEN` logic:

```
SELECT 
  (CASE
    WHEN a.price = b.price THEN 
      (CASE
        WHEN a.city = b.city THEN 'match!'
          ...
      )
    ELSE 
      ...

  END) as test
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you just need to `then null` on `false` comparison, eg:

```
t=# SELECT coalesce(
  case when 1=2 then 'match1' else null end
, case when 2=3 then 'match2' else null end
,case when 2=2 then 'match3' else null end
);
 coalesce
----------
 match3
(1 row)
```